# Out-Building Plumbing Rough-in layout

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, rough-in

I purchased my current property before all of the buildings were completed.  As such, I have a 60x80 outbuilding that has the plumbing roughed in for a bathroom, but the bathroom was not installed.  I am currently planning on completing the bathroom, but have never completed a project like this.

I am trying to understand what all of the drains are intended to be used for.  Specifically I do not understand which drain (Drain 1 or Drain 2 - both 2" pipes) is supposed to be for the sink.

In general, I am trying to understand what the layout for this bathroom was intended to be (i.e. where does sink, toilet, and walls go)

On the left side of the photo you can see the connections for a hydronic floor heating system.  Is it possible one of the drains is to be used for this system?

[image: Bathroom Rough-in]

Sketch of rough-in (Dimensions are in inches)
[image: Bathroom Rough-in sketch]

Comment: Off hand would place sink close to door, so you need to pass it on way out.  Second drain probably for shower/bathtub/second sink(?)

Comment: I'm trying to envision a sink/toilet/shower-tub layout that could use those drains, and I'm coming up blank.... It seems that someone "designed" this to have the toilet freestanding in the middle of the room!

Comment: Is "Drain 1" perhaps supposed to be a vent?  Because of its proximity to the Toilet Drain, I'd assume it's supposed to be the vent, and I don't see any other place where the vent might be. You're going to have problems with the toilet without one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the following layout that I believe will work.

I intend to build a wall from "Line in concrete floor to cover both Drain 1 and Water Main.   I'll cap Drain 1 until I find a use for it in the future.

I'll build a wall From Drain 2 to the back wall, thus leaving Drain to for a sink and providing correct dimensions  for the toilet to this wall.  See below for a quick mock up:

[[image: Mock up1]